# Working with coordinates in React native for different screen sizes?

Tags: react-native, coordinates, draggable

I have a list of draggable items who includes  one position X and one position Y and a name. The problem is that if I save the coordinates on a Iphone 11 and later display thoose on a Ipad it looks like a mess. So I wounder how save/get the coordinates so that I can use thoose on diffrent size of screens?

Here is my draggable item and my function their I sets the item postion.

```
  const [data, setData] = useState(mydata);


  const setItemPosition = (key, x, y) => {
    const updatedData = [...data];
    const item = data[key];
    item.X = x;
    item.Y = y;
    updatedData[key] = item;
    setData(updatedData);
  };

            {data.map((item, key) => (
              <Draggable
                x={10}
                y={200}
                key={key}
                renderColor="blue"
                renderSize={50}
                onShortPressRelease={() => setModalVisiblePlayer(true)}
                isCircle
                textcolor="#000000"
                renderText={() => {setItemName(key, name)}}
                onDragRelease={e => {
                  setItemPosition(
                    key,
                    e.nativeEvent.pageX,
                    e.nativeEvent.pageY,
                  );
                }}
              />
            ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similair use case where x/y coordinates are sent from one user to another user to be displayed on screen, each user potentially has a unique screen size. I use the function below to convert the incoming x/y to the current x/y for the current user.

```
let getRealCoords = useCallback((coords) => {
  // coords are the incoming x/y and the sending users' canvas/screen size
  // coords = {
  //   canvasX,
  //   canvasY,
  //   canvasWidth,
  //   canvasHeight
  // }
  let realX = coords.canvasX * (dimensionsRef.current.width / coords.canvasWidth);
  let realY = coords.canvasY * (dimensionsRef.current.height / coords.canvasHeight);

  return { x: realX.round(), y: realY.round() };
}, [styles])

Number.prototype.round = function(decimals = 0) { return Number(Math.round(this + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals) }
```

I've had good luck with this function/ calculation and the resulting coordinates are more or less dead on. Let me know if you need more documentation of how to use this getRealCoords function!

Comment: Thank you so much, It looks good! I will try this code tommorrow :)

Comment: Hello @t_killah, Is possible to get more documentation? :D

Comment: It's fairly straight forward/ plug and play. Pass an object containing the incoming x, y & the height/ width of the incoming users canvas, replace dimensionsRef.current.width/ height with the current users canvas width/ height and enjoy. Number.prototype.round is just a helper function to round to a certain decimal place.